# Road to holomorphic dynamics.

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, complex-dynamics

What is the best route in order to learn holomorphic dynamics? I mean, suppose that I started with Strogatz's dynamical systems, then what is the next book that I have to read?

Answer (score 4):

Try the books by Robert L. Devaney:

- [A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems](http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/books.html#first-course)
- [An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems](http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/books.html#intro)

You may also try this survey:

- P. Blanchard, [Complex analytic dynamics on the Riemann sphere](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183551835), *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*, 11 (1984), 85–141

and this collection:

- Robert L. Devaney and L. Keen (eds.), [Chaos and Fractals: The Mathematics behind the Computer Graphics](http://bookstore.ams.org/psapm-39), Proceedings of Symposia in Applied Mathematics 39, AMS, 1989.

Comment: Just a note that there's now a second edition of *A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems* and a third edition of *An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems*.